# respond to each request without having to wait until current stream is finished

Tags: node.js

I'm testing streaming by creating a basic node.js app code that basically streams a file to the response. Using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6928074/442580) and [here](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream).

But If I make a request from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, then open another browser and request another file, the second file will not start to download until the first one is finished. In my example I created a 1GB file. `dd if=/dev/zero of=file.dat bs=1G count=1`

But if I request three more files *while the first one is downloading*, the three files will start downloading simultaneously once the first file has finished.

**How can I change the code so that it will respond to each request as it's made and not have to wait for the current download to finish?**

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var i = 1;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    console.log('starting #' + i++);
    // This line opens the file as a readable stream
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('file.dat', { bufferSize: 64 * 1024 });

    // This will wait until we know the readable stream is actually valid before piping
    readStream.on('open', function () {
        console.log('open');
        // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
        readStream.pipe(res);
    });

    // This catches any errors that happen while creating the readable stream (usually invalid names)
    readStream.on('error', function(err) {
        res.end(err);
    });
}).listen(8000);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using?  Streams changed as of version v0.10.  http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/

Comment: not that this matters anymore because i've accepted your answer but for the record: `v0.10.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine the way it is.
I checked it with node v0.10.3 by making a few requests in multiple term sessions:

```
$ wget http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Two requests ran concurrently.
I get the same result when using two different browsers (i.e. Chrome & Safari).
Further, I can get concurrent downloads in Chrome by just changing the request url slightly, as in:

```
http://localhost:8000/foo
```

and

```
http://localhost:8000/bar
```

The behavior you describe seems to manifest when making multiple requests from the *same browser* for the *same url*.

This may be a browser limitation - it looks like the second request isn't even made until the first is completed or cancelled.

To answer your question, if you need multiple client downloads in a browser

1. Ensure that your server code is implemented such that file-to-url mapping is 1-to-many (i.e. using a wildcard).
2. Ensure your client code (i.e. javascript in the browser), uses a different url for each request.